# How to allow the props of every component to be defined in one central place in react native?

Tags: react-native

the question is clear. I think it can be done with react native elements. But how? I am very new to react native.

I read the documentation in [here](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/customization.html). It has a code like this:

```
import { ThemeProvider, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

const theme = {
  Button: {
    raised: true,
   },
};

// Your App
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button title="My Button" />
      <Button title="My 2nd Button" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

What if this part of the code:

```
const theme = {
  Button: {
    raised: true,
   },
};
```

was coded in another file. How will I make the buttons raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to aboard your problem.
First, if you want to use the same style for your react-native-elements components across certain files and **they are all the children of the same parent file**, you use this bit of code :

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Button title="My Button" />
  <Button title="My 2nd Button"/> // ... plus any other component that contains your react native elements components
</ThemeProvider>
```

for this case if you want to put your config variable in another file , you can do it like this :

- create a new file that contains your config variable let say for example a new file called config.js

```
// config.js file

export default {
    Button:{
        raised:true
    }
    // ... other RN-elements props
}

// or this

const theme = {
  Button: {
    raised: true,
   },
}

export {theme}
```

- then import it in your workspace like so :

```
// the file were you are using your themeProvider

import theme from "path_to_your_config.js_file"

// or respectively

import {theme} from "path_to_your_config.js_file"

// then use the variable theme as you like
```

the second way is that you create your own custom component and you style it however you want and you use it in your app.